# Is it possible to have 2 10000mAh power banks in a single carry on?

Tags: power

I am traveling abroad and I was wondering if I can take my 2 power banks with me in my carry on.

They are both identical power banks with 10000 mAh

[These are the ones I have](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ITILPZ4)

Comment: Yes, never had problems due to power banks in my hand luggage.

Comment: Never had problems myself (I've taken 2x10k, a 4k and a 2.5k). Of course it may depend on the airline / country's rules.

Comment: I think it would be useful if the question included information on the origin and destination countries.

Comment: I think as long as you don't carry more than a certain Wh (Watt/hour) it should be fine, I'm not sure about the number but I seem to remember it was around 100 Wh. Of course this may vary per country and per airline.

Comment: have a look at this one: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71390/can-you-put-an-ordinary-mac-laptop-with-the-battery-in-checked-luggage/71397#71397

Comment: @Bas how do I know how many watt/hour these have?

Comment: @Zaid it usually says so on the back of the powerbank in Wh

Comment: To get the energy stored, multiply by the capacity in Ah by the nominal voltage. 2 * 10Ah is 3.7 * 2 * 10 Wh = 74 Wh. Reference: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140375/confusion-power-bank-and-mobile-charging